# Discord bot profile application

Tags: discord, bots, pycord

How to create an application on the user's profile with pycord(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmt03.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMRc7.jpg)

I searched but did not find anything

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is happens only mobile view.

What is causing this is "user.command".

```
@bot.user_command(name="name")
async def name(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.respond(user.name)
```